# How to import excel sheet in laravel

Tags: excel, laravel, import

x axis is the width of curtain
y axis is the height of curtain
55,65,75,85 are the price value in $(dollar)

can anyone guide me step by step to import excel into MySQL database with fields

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look onto this package

https://laravel-excel.com/

I use this in all my excel-related projects and it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

check
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/installation.html

use with heading for easy import